# how can I give command line arguments in java and validate it

Tags: java

I am trying to code for 2 command line arguments  where the first one is 'u' or 'l', nothing else and second a dna sequence(a,c,g,t) between 10 -20 letters, using regular expression to validate both arguments and trying to print sequence in uppercase if arg. is u and in lowercase if arg is l.the problem is i am not getting desired output.
Please guide me how to do this code in java.

Comment: what have u tried till now?

Comment: If you find yourself struggling to parse Java command line, consider using Commons CLI: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BioHomework {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length < 2) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("two args required");
    }
    String sequence = args[1];
    if (!sequence.toLowerCase().matches("[atgc]{10,20}")){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("second arg should be 'atgc' string between 10 and 20 characters");
    }
    if ("u".equals(args[0])) {
      System.out.println(sequence.toUpperCase());
    } else if ("l".equals(args[0])) {
      System.out.println(sequence.toLowerCase());
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("first argument must be either 'u' or 'l'");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am new, thanks for telling me...

Answer (score 0):

Invoke your app this way `java app_name u a,c,g,t`

Then in the main method (since these are command line argument) you would have something like (Am assuming your main method parameter names is `args`):-

```
        if(args.length < 2){
            System.err.println("No or invalid argument entered");
        }else{
           String _case = args[0], dna_sequence = args[1]
           if (_case.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
                System.out.println(dna_sequence.toUpperCase());
            } else {
                System.out.println(dna_sequence.toLowerCase());
            }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @tmwanik.But is this validating my input too don't  i need regular expression for this.

Comment: I need to know why you are validating the input. Does it have a certain pattern? I should think this is for the dna sequence.

Comment: I need to validate because if any of the argument is invalid i have to print proper message and and end the program.

Comment: OK, then i need to edit

Comment: yes it is for a dna sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am reading javadocs and it says about ->java.util.regex.Pattern

Comment: which contain Pattern object, compile method and Matcher object, i was trying to do that.

Comment: What is your pattern?